# RedirectToAction not working when the main action is called from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 app, following `OrdersMain` View displays an input tag to add an order, below that tag it displays list of all existing orders. An `Add Order` button on the view calls the following action method `AddOrder(...)` that first adds the order to the database and then is supposed to redirect to the `OrdersMain(...)` action. But the redirect part is not working. The order is successfully added to the database. But `OrdersMain` View is not refreshed and hence the newly added order is not shown on the `OrdersMain` view right after the order is added. **Question**: What may be missing here and how I can make the newly order displayed on the `OrdersMain` view after the order is added? **Note**: I know the above can be achieved by using a `Form` and an `HttpPost`. But I'm interested in achieving the same using an `AJAX` call and `HttpGet`

**OrdersMain.cshtml** View: [Called from Action OrdersMain]

```
@model MyProj.Models.MyViewModel
...
...
Add Order: <input ....../>
...
List of Existing Orders:
<div>...</div>
...
@section scripts
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

$('.Addbtn').click(function () {

    var newOrdVal =  $('.txtAddRec').val();

            $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddOrder", "ContrlName")',
                data: { sNewOrdVal: newOrdVal },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(obj) {
            alert('Suceeded');
        },
                error: function(obj) {
            alert('Error occurred');
        }
    });
});


    });
    </script>
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(string sNewVal)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            ProdOrder  oRac = new ProdOrder { orderName = sNewVal };

            if (oRec != null)
            {
                _context.ProdOrder.Add(oRec);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("OrdersMain"); //this should reload the page and will display the new value on the list of orders on the page
        }
        catch
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("OrdersMain");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense to return a redirect response when you have an ajax form submit. Redirect response(302 response) is useful when you do a normal form submit.

I also recommend making your action method an Httppost action. Any method which updates data should be a POST.

You have few options to address your page refresh issue.

**1. Do a partial page update on the listing when ajax call is done**

In this approach, you udpate the markup for list of items already in the page so it reflects the new set of data. You can do this in multiple ways. One is to simply make an ajax call to get the html markup for all the items again and update the container which is holding the list of items. Another options is to have your action method return the markup needed for the new single item and use the jQuery `append()` method to append it to the existing list.

The below sample, returns a JSON response which has the Id of the new item saved and we will make another ajax call to get just that item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Addbtn').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var newOrdVal =  $('.txtAddRec').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Home")',
            data: { sNewVal: newOrdVal },
            type:'POST'
        }).done(function(res) {
               if (res.status === "success") {
                 $.get("@Url.Action("GetItem")?id=" + res.newItemId, function(newItem) {
                     $("#listContainer").append(newItem);
                 });
               }
       }).fail(function(a, b, c) {
        console.log('ajax call failed');
       });

   });

});
```

Assuming your AddOrder action method returns a json response with the new Item id and you have a Get `GetItem` which takes the action id and return the markup needed for the new item in the list.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(string sNewVal)
{
    ProdOrder  oRac = new ProdOrder { orderName = sNewVal };
     _context.ProdOrder.Add(oRec);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(new {status = "success", newItemId = oRec.Id});
}
public ActionResult GetItem(int id)
{
    var t=db.ProdOrder.Find(id);
    //I am simply returning the orderName wrapped in p tag.
    // You may change this to call a Partial view 
    // which returns the markup for the single item 
    return Content("<p>" + t.orderName + "</p>");
}
```

**2. Reload the page**

You can reload your page using javascript in the success handler of your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  // your ajax params
}).done(function(res){
   window.location.href  = window.location.href;

}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log('ajax call failed');
});
```

I would not prefer reloading the page. Because that totally defeats my purpose of using an ajax form post.

If you use a front end MV* framework like angular, all you do is remove the item the data source (which might be an array) which is used to render the items in the list.

Comment: I agree with your following suggestion because that way user can see his/her change right away, as well: Any method which updates data should be a POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can not move the `ajax post` or `ajax get` to the new `view`. When you use the `ajax` , the `view` is placed in the `Obj`. To do this, you need to `submit` or `Re location` your page. In that case, the practice of the redirect is done correctly